# php не воспринимает ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, php, html

в index.php хранится следующий код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="generate()">
    <h1>check</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generate() {
            $.ajax({  
                url:      "index.php",
                type:     "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data:     {"targetvalue":23},
                success: function() {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $temp = $_POST['targetvalue'];
            if(!empty($temp)) {
                echo $temp;
            }
            else {
                echo 'isnt working';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'isnt post request';
        }
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

при загрузке страницы, должна срабатывать функция generate() из javascript, которая вызывает ajax-запрос. запрос, методом post, передает на эту же страницу значение переменной "targetvalue" - 23. далее идет php проверка: post ли идет запрос, и в случае, если это так, и при этом, переменная не пустая - она выводится, иначе - соответственная ошибка

и так, в моем случае выводится следующее:

[image: результат]

в консоли мы видим "success", что означает, что ajax-запрос был успешно отправлен, а на самой странице мы видим "isnt post request", из чего следует, что php попросту не видит никаких post запросов.

devtools в браузере говорит о следующем:

[image: test.com - заголовки]
[image: test.com - предпросмотр]

[image: index.php - заголовки]
[image: index.php - предпросмотр]

использую openserver

в чем может быть проблема, и как ее можно решить?

Comment: А Вы отправляете запрос в файл `handler.php` но вся логика на самом деле лежит в `index.php`, так?

Comment: @Simon ошибка в составлении вопроса. и там, и там у меня index.php. исправил

Comment: @macr0n, посмотрите в DevTools браузера какой именно делается запрос и с какими параметрами. Есть достаточное количество факторов, от чего запрос мог дойти до сервера не таким, как ожидается. Как первый шаг — посмотрите что браузер делает именно такой запрос, как это требуется.

Comment: @7-zete-7 добавил сведения о запросах с devtools в тему

Comment: Вы используете встроенный в PHP сервер, или полноценный типа apache/nginx?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, использую openserver

Comment: А что именно вы ожидаете от этого кода? Страница загружается, после подгрузки делает запрос на сервер, и при любом исходе делает console.log. Для того чтобы открыть страницу в браузере делается GET, а не POST запрос, который выводит ваш первый результат. При POST запросе вы ничего не делаете кроме console.log.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, ожидаю вывод значения переменной targetvalue.

Comment: Тогда либо возвращайте значение из PHP и заменяйте им то что есть на странице, либо делайте обычную форму с submit кнопкой.

Comment: ваш код будет выводить html код вне зависимости от метода запроса (POST, GET). Чтобы ваша задумка работала, при GET нужно выводить html с js, а при POST только нужную информацию

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, суть как раз таки в том, что бы сделать запрос принимался без перезагрузки, по этому обычная форма не подойдет. а на счет первого - как такое реализовать?

Comment: @ArchDemon как это можно провернуть?

Comment: `if ... else ...`

Comment: @ArchDemon, имею ввиду, что когда выводить? и при каких условиях?

Comment: ну я всё расписал выше. Ещё точнее просто не смогу

Comment: @ArchDemon, таким образом, имеешь ввиду? https://gist.github.com/macr0n1/3d23d556f8ea8e0d82b6f820bf6f079b/cc04877fac73676c5e55fd65c0d71b30ee6119d8